# Using Setf Syntax in a Loop

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What is the proper way to do a setf for the variable below?

```
CG-USER(279): (defun LETTERSEARCH (string1 string2) 
  (let ((newString nil))
  (let ((letterSearchOn nil))
  (loop for i from 0 below (length string1)
      always
          (setf (letterSearchOn (char string1 i))           
          (print letterSearchOn))))))
LETTERSEARCH
CG-USER(280): (stringprod "abc" "abc")

NIL 
Error: `(SETF LETTERSEARCHON)' is not fbound
[condition type: UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
CG-USER(281):
```

Comment: Could you speak to the intent of this code a bit? What`s the point of `newString` and `string2`?

Comment: Note that lispers usually use hyphens to seperated words rather than
CamelCase. `newString` → `new-string`, `letterSearchOn` →
`letter-search-on`, …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be `(setf letterSearchOn (char string1 i))`.

The way `(setf)` works in Common Lisp is really cool; it's a macro, but the macro expander which is used depends on the argument. For example:

```
(defparameter a (list 1))
(setf (car a) 2)
a    ; => (2)
(setf (cdr a) (list 3))
a    ; => (2 3)
```

Does that seem strange? `(car a)` is a function... how can you "set" it to a new value??? The answer is that if the first argument to `(setf)` is a list which starts with `car`, it expands to code which sets the `car` of a cons cell. If the first argument is a list which starts with `cdr`, it expands to code which sets the `cdr` of a cons cell. And so on for vectors, hash tables, etc. etc.

You can even define your own `(setf)` macros, which can expand the range of things which `(setf)` knows how to set. In this case, you are passing `(letterSearchOn (char string1 i))`, so it thinks that you want it to use a special `letterSearchOn` macro expander, but no such `setf` macro expander has been defined.

Comment: This helps, but I still do not quite see the light.  So I declare it as (defparameter a (list 1))?  Then I set it as (setf (car a) (list 0)) since I just want to store one letter in it?  Later that letter will be to search off of.

Comment: @JohnGabrielson, that was just an example demonstrating the interesting properties of `setf`. In your case, you just need to remove an unneeded pair of parentheses, as I pointed out in the first line of my answer.

Comment: By the way, if you want to iterate over the letters in a string and print them, you can do it more easily with `(loop for letterSearchOn across string1 always (print letterSearchOn))`